# Why can't I struct.unpack an unsigned char and a string afterwards in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, networking, struct, udp

I'm making a server in Python for my GMS 2 project and I'm writing a client in GameMaker. But somehow when I use only:

```
struct.unpack('B', data[:1])[0]
```

It works but when I'm trying to send a string afterwards:

```
struct.unpack('Bs', data[:1])[0]
```

It gives me an following error:

```
mid = struct.unpack('Bs', data[:1])[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 2 bytes
```

This is the entire code I'm using to receive data:

```
import socket
import struct


UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5555


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes

    msg_id = struct.unpack('Bs', data[:1])[0]
    print(msg_id)
    #if mid == 0:
       # struct.unpack('Bp', data[:1])[0]
```

And this is how I send it in GameMaker:

```
buffer_seek(global.Buffer, buffer_seek_start, 0);
buffer_write(global.Buffer, buffer_u8, 0); //Sends which PACKET ID we should decode
buffer_write(global.Buffer, buffer_string, global.Username); //Sends username as a "buffer_string" type
network_send_udp_raw(socket,"127.0.0.1", 5555, global.Buffer, buffer_tell(global.Buffer));
```

Comment: What is unclear with this error? You need a buffer of 2 bytes but provide only one byte.

Comment: Hey Daniel, am I not using 2 bytes? I'm not sure how to fix this thing, it's really simpler using GameMaker and I'm searching for 2 days without any luck of an answer...